# How to Get Json from url then add to table in html?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have this JSON

```
[{"Content":"asd",
  "Title":"asd",
  "Author":"asd",
  "ID":2,
  "Created":"2019-06-30 01:41:53.0"
}]
```

How to add these to a table in HTML?

Comment: What does your table look like and what's its HTML? And what have you tried?

Comment: i have done book Store with api  like : http://localhost:8081/Store/rest/articles and it return json data like above , i want to make table for these  as  first Title and below the information ,  like store.html , just i want to add json data from url to show in table  Store.html  doesn't matter what it looks like.

Comment: Then you can [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) your JSON and display on your HTML body.

Answer (score 0):

let's JSON file name is users.json, then

```
     fetch('users.json')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(users=>{
        users.forEach(user=>{
            out+=`
            <div id='module'>
            <h3>Name: ${user.name}<h3>
            <h3>Email: ${user.email}<h3>
            <h3>Number: ${user.number}<h3>
            </div>`
        })
        parentDiv.innerHTML=out;
        })
```

Comment: your code didn't work for me could you give more information because i am new in these things

Comment: can you please show me your code where do you want to put your JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({ url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', type: "get", dataType: "json",

success: function(data) { drawTable(data); } });

function drawTable(data) { for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { drawRow(data[i]); } }

function drawRow(rowData) { var row = $("") $("#personDataTable").append(row); row.append($("" + rowData.id + "")); row.append($("" + rowData.title + "")); row.append($("" + rowData.userId + "")); }